# Hyperlinks in Footnotes over Two Pages

Tags: hyperref

A new bug in macOS High Sierra has highlighted (in cyan) a problem with the way \url{} hyperlinks are made when the link overflows to a different page.

The below image demonstrates that the hyperlink is attached to the correct text in the footnote of the first page; but then overflows to hyperlink the first text on the second page.

Is there a simple solution to this problem that does *not* involve manually line-splitting the offending URL?

[image: Hyperlink]

Comment: do you mean this is PDF viewer dependent? ``A new bug in macOS High Sierra`` is far from clear. Provide a small compilable example, people are not going to spend 10 minutes recompose a document only to reproduce your problem. Hyperref works the same on all systems.

Comment: The short answer is no.  But instead of \url you can use \href.  You should still see the url if you place the mouse over the link.